# Comparisons of columns returned by linq to sql queries

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've done this before, and I'm drawing a blank on how I did it.

I'm using linq to sql to compare list from different databases on different servers.  I can't combine the queries due to the complexety of the actual query and huge amounts of data this will process.

```
var query1 = (from u in database1server1
           select new
          { PrimaryLine1 = u.PrimaryLine1, 
            PrimaryLine2 = u.PrimaryLine2, 
            PrimaryLine3 = u.PrimaryLine3, 
            }).ToList().ToString();



var query2 = (from m in database2server2
          select new
          { PrimaryLine1 = m.PrimaryLine1, 
           PrimaryLine2 = m.PrimaryLine2, 
           PrimaryLine3 = m.PrimaryLine3, 
           }).ToList().ToString();
```

I need to account for differences in these list lists, column by column. So, I need a list of all the PrimaryLine1 values which are in database1server1 but not database2server2... and so on PrimaryLine2, PrimaryLine3, etc.

How can I build the string dataMismatces so I can generate a neat list for the end user?

```
 string failedTests = null; // in
 failedTests = string.Join("\n", dataMismatces);
```

Comment: Why are you invoking `ToString`? How do you compare the two lists? Do you compare item1 from server 1 with item1 from server 2? do these two queries return the same number of items? How do you know there are ordered correctly? Or is there a key that you use to identify the same item in the two databases?

Comment: Why ToString() at the end of each query? I think you have to process each primaryLines after getting query1 and query2. Then `uPrimaryLines1.Except(mPrimaryLines1)`